# Find h4 tag using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm really new to web scraping and saw a few questions similar to mine but those solutions didn't work for me. So I'm trying to scrape this website: https://www.nba.com/schedule for the h4 tags, which hold the dates and times for upcoming basketball games. I'm trying to use beautiful soup to grab that tag but it always returns and empty list. Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
schedule = doc.find_all('h4')
```

I saw something in another answer about the h4 tags being inside  tags and I tried to use a json module but couldn't get that to work. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. To load the data you can use following example:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://cdn.nba.com/static/json/staticData/scheduleLeagueV2_1.json"
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for g in data["leagueSchedule"]["gameDates"]:
    print(g["gameDate"])
    for game in g["games"]:
        print(
            game["homeTeam"]["teamCity"],
            game["homeTeam"]["teamName"],
            "-",
            game["awayTeam"]["teamCity"],
            game["awayTeam"]["teamName"],
        )
    print()
```

Prints:

```
10/3/2021 12:00:00 AM
Los Angeles Lakers - Brooklyn Nets

10/4/2021 12:00:00 AM
Toronto Raptors - Philadelphia 76ers
Boston Celtics - Orlando Magic
Miami Heat - Atlanta Hawks
Minnesota Timberwolves - New Orleans Pelicans
Oklahoma City Thunder - Charlotte Hornets
San Antonio Spurs - Utah Jazz
Portland Trail Blazers - Golden State Warriors
Sacramento Kings - Phoenix Suns
LA Clippers - Denver Nuggets

10/5/2021 12:00:00 AM
New York Knicks - Indiana Pacers
Chicago Bulls - Cleveland Cavaliers
Houston Rockets - Washington Wizards
Memphis Grizzlies - Milwaukee Bucks

...and so on.
```

Comment: Also, he can use selenium instead of BeautifulSoup to scrape from dynamic websites

Comment: So how did you know to use that URL instead of the one I was using. Is there some sort of default formula or did you just google search for a static website?

Comment: @KoleDavis If you open Firefox Developer Tools (Chrome has something similar) -> Network Tab, you can observe all requests the page is doing. One of the request is the URL with the data.